# return the count for element in a has_many relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have 2 models one is listing and user 
user has_many listings
listing belongs_to user

i have a view setup , i want to display for each user their own listings count ,i try this code :

```
<% User.all.each do |user| %>
<%= user.listings.count %>
<% end %>
```

i want to grab the listing count for each user . i found a bunch of solution here , all return the loop .other solutions i tried is to create a class method .

```
def count_listings
  Listing.where(:user_id => user.id).count
end
```

try to call this way `<%= User.count_listings%>` it doesn't work .
for some reason there something i'm missing ,can't quite figure it out .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The :counter_cache option can be used to make finding the number of belonging objects more efficient. Consider these models:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
end
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders
end
```

With these declarations, asking for the value of @customer.orders.size requires making a call to the database to perform a COUNT(*) query. To avoid this call, you can add a counter cache to the belonging model:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer, counter_cache: true
end
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders
end
```

With this declaration, Rails will keep the cache value up to date, and then return that value in response to the size method.

Although the :counter_cache option is specified on the model that includes the belongs_to declaration, the actual column must be added to the associated model. In the case above, you would need to add a column named orders_count to the Customer model. You can override the default column name if you need to:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer, counter_cache: :count_of_orders
end
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders
end
```

Counter cache columns are added to the containing model's list of read-only attributes through attr_readonly.

source: [Rails guide on associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs-to-association-reference)
 ..scroll down to options of belongs_to

Comment: Please let me know if my context is wrong, which I am realising after posting the answer.

Comment: Also tell wether you want to optimise the n+1 query problem or something else.

Comment: no your context was the correct approach , it's simple and to the point

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is what you show in the example you can do it better as follows

```
<% Listing.group(:user_id).count.each do |user, count| %>
  <%= "user: #{user} has #{count} listings" %>
<% end %>
```

This does a single query to the database and fetches only what you need.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, user_id AS user_id FROM `listings` GROUP BY user_id
```

and returns a hash like:

```
{
  1: 123,
  2: 231
}

#{ user_id: count }
```